# How to fix "required fields" in PDF form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, button

I tried to use JavaScript for a control mechanism inside a pdf form. There are many fields, checkboxes etc. some of them are required, some of them don't and some of the required only shows when you check a certain box.

My problem now is: some of the required fields are dropdown menus or option fields and the javascript don't show that they are "missing" when I click the button. If I erase the `(f.value.length<1))` part it is showing all required fields but don't recognize the ones who are filled e.g. with a dropdown element, text or similiar 'cause the condition is missing.

I need a code which finds all required fields and sees if they are empty or filled with ANYTHING and a way to exclude some fields, cause some are only visible when a certain checkbox is activated or a way to include those fields only when the certain box is activated.

Thank you!

```
kontrollieren(); 
function kontrollieren() {  
    var feld;  
    feld = "" 
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {  
        var fName = this.getNthFieldName(i);  
        var f = this.getField(fName);  
        if ((f.type != "button") && f.required && (f.value.length < 1)) {  
            feld = feld + fName + "\n"; 
        }  
    }  
    if (feld == ""){  
        app.doc.print(); 
    }  
    else {
        app.alert("Bitte füllen sie vor dem Drucken alle Pflichtfelder aus.\nFehlende Felder:\n\n" + feld); 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all of the inputs should have a `name` as well as a `value` field. You may need to identify the input (and thus validation method employed) this way.

In situations such as these, where there are multiple inputs, and multiple conditionals determining what's `required`, try to catch the `false`. I'd employ something similar to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {  
    var fName = this.getNthFieldName(i);  
    var f = this.getField(fName);  
    if ((f.type != "button") && f.required) { 

        // For a Select Input
        if (f.name === 'selectInputName') {
            // Or whatever the 'default' value is that represents not selecting a value
            if (f.value !== 'Select One') {
                feld = feld + fName + '\n';
            }
        }

        // For a checkbox
        if (f.name === 'checkboxInputName' && f.checked) {
            feld = feld + fName + '\n';
        }

        // For an input
        if (f.name === 'textInputName' && f.length.value > 0) {
            feld = feld + fName + '\n';
        }

    }  
}
```

I'm not 100% how your structure works - `getNthFieldName()` && `getField()` are two functions I am not familiar with, but hopefully, the idea above is still relatable.